# unauthenticated calls return 200 status

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application. I have added a security layer for it goes like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${allowed.paths}")
    private List<String> allowedPaths;

    @Autowired
    private TestCenterAuthProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(allowedPaths.toArray(new String[0]))
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

this provides `POST localhost:8080/login` endpoint by default with default HTML representation.

Now any unauthenticated call I do returns 200 OK with HTML response for the login page. I need this to just return 403. and I am unable to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

insert

```
.exceptionHandling()
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                        new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint(),
                        new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"))
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
```

to enable 403's